# Make apt install packages from a specific repository

Tags: r, ubuntu, debian, apt, cran

Is there any way to have `apt` install a package from a specific launchpad repository?

I would like to set up a little test server and install all of the 1000+ `r-cran-*` packages from the `cran2deb4ubuntu` [launchpad repository](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/c2d4u). As of last month, all packages in this repository [are build for R 3.0.1](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2013/06/cran2deb4ubuntu-updated-for-r-301-and-ubuntu-1304.html). So I install a copy of R 3.0.1 and then do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository marutter/c2d4u
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-*
```

However, this will also install all of the `r-cran-*` packages form `universe` which are build for R 2.15, and hence will fail to load. Is there an easy way to install the packages only from `c2d4u`? Or alternatively, is there a way to blacklist the `r-cran-` packages in universe from `apt`?

Comment: This is probably more suitable for superuser, or askubuntu.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository - the -t option of apt-get is what you are looking for.

Comment: Google 'apt pinning' which lets you give preferences / rankings to different repos.

Comment: @TeTeT The `-t` option specifies a target distribution (E.g. `raring`) but all my repositories target the same distribution.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel pinning too is done by *release*, not by *repository*. The problem here is that i have multiple repositories for the same release.

Comment: It's a one-off problem due to the 3.0 migrations as the universe package have same or higher versions. So maybe don't 'wildcard' install til that transition is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is simply install all packages and then remove the ones with an old build. I.e.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-bioc-*
sudo apt-get install r-cran-
```

And then in R:

```
which(installed.packages()[,"Built"] < 3.0)
```